# Publish Flutter package to local .m2 or private Nexus-Repository

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I've created a Flutter package with some code, that I use in my projects. I don't want to copy code from one project to the next one, so I'd like to have this code in a shared library.

In the pubspec.yaml there is a key word "publish_to:", but the documentation about it is very meagre.

The only thing I've found is

```
flutter packages pub publish
```

to publish the library to pub.dev - but that's not what I want.

(At the moment) I don't want to share my Flutter package with others. I'd like to have it in my local .m2 directory or my private Nexus repository. Is there a way to publish a Flutter package directly to .m2 or Nexus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your best bet is to host your code in a git repository and use git references in your pubspec.yaml as per [these instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages). It doesn't look like there's any planned support for third-party package repositories like Nexus (be sure to let your needs be known to the Dart team).

If you'd like, you can also host your own server using this [official pub_server package](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server).

Comment: Note the official pub server package is archived and no longer maintained or recommended. 

The only more up to date alternative I have found is https://github.com/bytedance/unpub.